# With MongoDB, is it possible receive notifications of 3rd party edits via .NET Reactive Extensions (RX)?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, mongodb, system.reactive

I'm wondering if anybody knows if its possible to get live notifications of any edits to a MongoDB database via Reactive Extensions (RX) in C#?

This would mean that any 3rd party could edit the MongoDB database, and a service could monitor the edits and instantly react to them in real time.

**What I have tried**

I have spent a large amount of time researching this on both Google and elsewhere, and been through all of the NuGet packages that might be related. The only match I could find [involved Java, and was in German](https://github.com/dwursteisen/rx-mongo).

**Update 1**

Looking at tailable cursors, here:

http://www.warski.org/blog/2012/11/event-streaming-with-mongodb/

Comment: This is more of a MongoDB question.... once you have events being published from MongoDB, you can just use `Observable.Create`

Comment: @Chistopher Harris It would be great if I had the luxuruy of controlling every process that writes to the MongoDB database, but I dont. There may be 3rd party writes to the database, i.e. a manual edit by a human using RoboMongo.

Comment: Yeppers. That's kind of my point. You have two questions: 1) How do I get events from MongoDB, and 2) How do turn those events into observables?

Comment: Youre correct, its actually two questions. I'm keeping a close eye on the proposed Change Notification Stream API mentioned below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How to track 3rd party changes to MongoDB data

I'm not aware of a specific Reactive Extensions implementation, however the general approach (as at MongoDB 2.6) would be to [create a tailable cursor](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-tailable-cursor/) on a capped collection -- the same approach taken in the German blog post you referenced.

With a tailable cursor on the [replication oplog](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-oplog/) you will get a stream of changes across all databases that you can filter by namespace and operation (insert, delete, update) as appropriate.

#### What if I'm not using a replica set?

While an oplog is normally only created for the purposes of replication, if you have a standalone MongoDB server you can also run it as a single node replica set with the sole benefit being the *oplog*.

By default, the [oplog size](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-oplog/#oplog-size) on 64-bit systems (excepting OS X) will be 5% of free disk space. You can use the [`oplogSize`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongod/#cmdoption--oplogSize) configuration parameter to specify a different oplog size. If you don't intend to use replication, you can probably reduce the oplog size to something more suitable for your change notification. If you're not sure on an appropriate size, I would leave at the default and later follow the tutorial to [Change the Oplog Size](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/change-oplog-size/) if needed.

To convert your standalone server into a single node replica set you essentially need to:

- Add a [`replSet`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongod/#cmdoption--replSet) configuration value with a unique name for your replica set (and optionally, `oplogSize` if you want an initial size different from the default)
- Restart your MongoDB server so this change takes effect
- As a once off in the `mongo` shell, run [`rs.initiate()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/rs.initiate/) to create the replica set configuration and preallocate the oplog

Comment: You may also want to watch/upvote [SERVER-13932: Change Notification Stream API](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-13932) in the MongoDB issue tracker. This is a feature suggestion for a server-based notification API that could provide an abstraction over reading the oplog directly.

Comment: This would be the equivalent functionality to Sql Service Broker, in that any application can get notified of any edits to a 3rd party table.