# How to listen to mongoDB changes using C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have created the MongoDB Service and writing values to MongoDB using one program. Another program would need to subscribe to these changes. Like Events. Whenver a collection gets a new value I need to get a call back to my new C# program.  Is this possible ?

Comment: Maybe this is answered here (http://stackoverflow.com/q/24970088/265165) or there (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10014839) at StackOverflow. There is no other possibility right now as far as I know

Comment: In general, if you want a queue, use a queue. I am pretty sure Microsoft has "embraced" JMS as well. Or have a look at ActiveMQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its possible using the Tail-able Cursor in MongoDB. Create the MongoDB service as a replica service.Create only primary server(if more than one server is not used.).Oplog table will be create in the MongoDB Server. This table will get reflected for each and every changes happens in the database. The table details which are changed will be present in the Oplog table,

Create a Tailable cursor in the table and create an Event and event listener to listen to the changes in this table. 
 [Tailable cursor](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-tailable-cursor/)

This is the only work around solution I can find out till now. Its works like a charm !! :). As I have started working on QT C++ and SQlite I forgot about this qustion. Hope this helps anyone in future.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think that this i possible. I would implement another Document in the MongoDB, where all changes are inserted to. Your second program can check for new changes in the Document. Than you have a robust pull-system. Maybe you can call the Document some thing like **Notification** or **ChangeLog**.

(Solution without ReplicaSet)