# MongoDb/NodeJs: Observe collection changes

Tags: node.js, mongodb, observable

Is there a version of an observable collection for MongoDb-nodejs-driver?

I have seen that there is an implementation of an ObservableCollection for .Net, Java and Ruby.

For JS I could think of a combination of a [capped collection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/capped-collections/) and [tailable cursors](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/tailable-cursors/). This could work but the limitation is that the notification would come only for the latest added doc.

Comment: for .net observable collection is a internal object not mongodb collection - name could mislead you. see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24975912/5919473)

Comment: Yeah, I could imagine that. I wondered if somebody made an implementation already.

Comment: see this link provided above - that's a neat solution

Comment: I missed the link but it is just what I suggested in the question - capped collections used with tailable cursors. I have found a lib https://github.com/scttnlsn/mubsub that implements this model. I am just testing it. It seems promising.,