# Observable mongodb with .NET Core

Tags: mongodb, asp.net-core, observable

I am looking how to leverage MongoDB cursor and just found this Java example:
https://gist.github.com/viniciusccarvalho/bbada1e463baf61b2088:

```
package us.devguild.reactive.mongo;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.DBCursor;
import com.mongodb.DBObject;
import com.mongodb.DB;
import rx.Observable;

@Component
public class ObservableMongo {


    private DB mongoDB;

       @Autowired
    public ObservableMongo(DB db){
        this.mongoDB = db;
    }

    public Observable<DBObject> toObservable(String collection, DBObject query){

        return Observable.create(subscriber -> {
            DBObject dbo = null;
            try {
                DBCollection dbCol = mongoDB.getCollection(collection);
                final DBCursor cursor = dbCol.find(query);
                while(cursor.hasNext()){
                    dbo = cursor.next();
                    subscriber.onNext(dbo);
                }
                subscriber.onCompleted();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                subscriber.onError(e);
            }

        });
    }

}
```

Is it possible to achieve the same in .NET Core?

Comment: The java code you posted doesn't look any different than using Rx.NET an IQueryable. MongoDB C# Driver has three different Apis you can use. It has the classical cursor based API (one using `InsertOrReplace` or `FindAsync` with `FindOptions`), it has a fluid API (one using `.Find(...)`) and it has LINQ API (one with `collection.AsQueryable<MyEntity>()`) which uses the IQueryable LINQ API. Later one should be easy to use with RX.NET to subscribe for a stream

Comment: But this will only stream the current query once (rather than loading it all into memory first). If you want to detect changes from outside (i.e. wenn an document is written, added or deleted), you need a different approach. Check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24970088/with-mongodb-is-it-possible-receive-notifications-of-3rd-party-edits-via-net-r on how to track 3rd party changes